# Show the notes pane: make it the default in a PowerPoint template

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

The notes pane is not visible by default in PowerPoint. I observe that people are not even aware that the notes pane exists. I wonder whether it's possible to change the default state of that pane visibility in a PowerPoint template.

I have tried:

- make the notes pane visible, then save as POTX file. This does not work, it is invisible again when creating a new presentation from the template.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is it possible to change the default state of that (notes) pane?

You can change the "Default View":

> By default, PowerPoint opens in Normal view, displaying the
>   thumbnails, notes and slide view. If you prefer, however, you can
>   specify that PowerPoint open in a different view, such as Slide Sorter
>   view, Slide Show view, Notes Page view, and variations on Normal view.
>
> - Click the Microsoft Office Button Office button image , and then click PowerPoint Options.
> - In the PowerPoint Options dialog box, click Advanced on the left pane.
> - Under Display, in the Open all documents using this view list, select the view that you want to set as the new default, and then
>     click OK.

Source [Change the default view](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-default-view-8d82ef84-c016-4ef4-b477-e319090de0eb?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: This settings seems to apply per computer. I was hoping to find something per POTX file.

Comment: The idea is quite ok. I'll see if that setting can be published via group policies to all employees. That would help.